# Singleton Resources Shared Across ReactJS Components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, module, singleton

I am using TypeScript.

I've been struggling with figuring out how to use the module system to create singleton objects to be shared across multiple ReactJS components. I have followed three different tutorials but have not gotten a working use case. I suspect that TypeScript may be messing with the code samples.

- http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/singleton_pattern_in_es6_and
- https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-design-patterns-singleton/
- https://k94n.com/es6-modules-single-instance-pattern

Basically I want to have common functionality shared between ReactJS components and I want that functionality to be accessed via importing the module and then somehow accessing the same object regardless of which file is accessing the module.

The 'context' feature of ReactJS seems to be one way to do this, but it is explicitly frowned upon by React themselves.

Comment: React should be coupled up with Redux (Global state management).

Comment: What exactly is the problem you get? Maybe posting some of your code examples here will help? All three examples gives you valid implementation even though they are in javascript. If you want pure typescript one - here is one more example: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/singleton.html